# illustrator text box resize

Tags: resize, adobe, adobe-illustrator

Good day good people of Stackoerflow,

I encountered the following problem, I cannot resize textbox in Illustrator or Images.[Example for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44bh8.jpg)

[example for text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSkQI.jpg)

I tried the Free Transform Tool it didn't help. I am using Illustrator CC 21.0.2 64-bits.

Answer (score 0):

for image: -click on the image after look top tool bars your show a tool "transform" please look below image.[image: top right:-transform]

click this menu fix height and width and after that make a new template and copy paste to this image and export in .png format with 72 ppi resolution

Answer (score 0):

The text box maybe set to 'automatic' in the Type>Area Type Options... Uncheck the option and it should fix the issue